# Command output piped to the less utility randomly gives Suspended (tty output) on Monterey 12.6.3

Tags: terminal, command-line

Piping the results of a command to `less` in Terminal randomly produces Suspended (tty output) in about every 1 in 20 tries of a piped command such as:

```
ls -l | less

Suspended (tty output)
[1] 2051 2052
```

This should **never** happen. I tried `stty -tostop` to no avail. Restarting Terminal and rebooting macOS do not help. There is no problem with xterm (XQuartz).

Monterey 12.6.3 with MacBook M1 Pro and tcsh 6.21.00 as shell.

Is this a `less` bug or a Terminal bug or this combination fails?

Comment: What’s the specific question?

Comment: Is this a bug? This is a fairly new machine with the latest Monterey update. This random problem should never happen.

Comment: Try updating to 12.6.5, just in case.

Comment: Is `ls` or `less` aliased to something else?

Comment: Nope. No aliases: `which less` gives ` /usr/bin/less` and `ls` is a shell built-in. I'm using tcsh. I'm not seeing this problem with bash/zsh. Perhaps a tcsh issue?

Comment: The problem persists after updating to Monterey 12.7.